# how to improve redux state performance with Redux Toolkit?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I am developing a project with reactJS and managing the state with Redux.
I am loading the initial state data with createAsyncThunk(). But it seems the web page is being more slow than using react useState() hook. In both case, I have used fetch() to load data from server.
How can I improve the data loading performance from state?

Comment: "Slow" is a very broad term :)  Can you give some more specifics about what performance issues you're seeing?  Is this about: the number of React re-renders, how long those re-renders take, the time the network requests take to complete, or something else?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.